# VB.NET - Split text doc using blank lines

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a text doc with multiple lines but each "subject" is separated by a blank line.. like..

```
Block 1
   Line 1
   Line 2

Block 2
   Line 1
   Line 2
```

And so on. I have tried lots of variants using vbcr and the like.. but can't get each block to be separated by the "blank lines". The goal is to use each block's data individually.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any examples on how you plan to use it? We can help you parse it, but into what data structure is the question I have.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unclear on what you're trying to do: are you trying to parse each "block" of data separately, and need to recognize a blank line as a blank line?

If that is the case, you could read each line as follows:

```
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
Dim tempString As String = ""

Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
   tempString = objReader.ReadLine().Trim()
   if tempString.equals("") Then ' we have a blank line ...
   Else
     ' Do something else with the tempstring line
   End If
Loop
```

There may be more sophisticated ways to do this, but this is what I'd do.

Answer (score 0):

Try regular Expressions.

```
Import System.Text.RegularExpressions 'may be needed in your file to use below code...

Dim blocks() As String = Regex.Split(myData, "\n[ \t]*\n")
' regex looks for the occurrence of an enter char "\n" following by an optional amount of whitespace "[ \t]*" following by another enter character
```

You may also need to intermix some "\r" in that regex as a "carriage return \r" and a "new line \n" are sometimes mixed in different ways in data. 
"\r\n" = vbCrLf
"\r" = vbCr
"\n" = vbLf

Comment: OK.. I left out or didn't explain thoroughly.. sorry about that. Think of the blank line as the delimiter and each block/paragraph.. etc.. will be processed as a group. So it's several lines of data.. blank line... several lines of data... blank line. This is why carriage returns weren't working because each line has carriage return only SOME of the lines don't have text.. or are "blank".

Answer (score 0):

Dim subjectsWithLines() as string=split(stringThatYouReadFromFile,chr(10))

Now there are different kinds of BLANK lines, if chr(10) doesn't work then try using chr(13) or Environment.newline

ChicagoMike's answer works too, but due different kind of "BLANK LINES", use

tempString.Count<1 instead equals